# Why don't CSS images behave like HTML images

Tags: html, css

Why do images defined in CSS (like backgrounds, lists marker, ...etc.) not behave in the same way in the browser as HTML images? For example, they can't be selected by the mouse, and you can't right click on them.

Answer (score 5):

Images are generally used in CSS for one thing, backgrounds. Which means they aren't **used** for the same things HTML images are being used for (displaying the actual image as part of the content).

When an image is part of the content, it can be saved and copied etc, because it
is likely to be considered interesting by the reader. Backgrounds (or list-markers etc) however, are less likely (unless the reader is a developer) to interest the reader enough to want to copy them. Instead, the focus is on the actual content of the element (which the background was applied to).

Comment: [One of the current "hot questions"](http://superuser.com/questions/473678/how-can-i-copy-nytimes-com-slideshow-images-to-the-clipboard) shows this assumption is not always true though

Comment: @MartinSmith: That's how it **should** be used. Of course I can replace all of my images with empty divs and set a background, or replace all my backgrounds with absolutely positioned images with a negative z-index. CSS backgrounds should never be part of the content of an article/blog post/whatever, it's merely for eye candy.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is a question for browser vendors why they allow certain behavior only when dealing with `<img>` tag.

However, you can use dev tools/Firebug/whatever and you can download the image file.